# styling a context menu

Tags: android, sdk, android-contextmenu

I noticed some context menus in various tutorials on the web look different than mine, i.e. there a title with an arrow in a circle at the top.  Mine is just a square box with items.  Is this just a newer version of the context menu, or is there a way to style the menu?

I'd like to center the items, set a backcolor, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextMenu` has several methods like [`setHeaderTitle()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html#setHeaderTitle%28int%29)(for adding a title, but you have [`setHeaderView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextMenu.html#setHeaderView%28android.view.View%29) for more complex stuff) so you can customize the ContextMenu in the method `onCreateContextMenu()`.